# Fetching the data before the <br> tag in simplehtmldom

Tags: php, cakephp, simple-html-dom

I have a html tag as follows:-

```
<p>
"SOme important data1"
<br>
<br>
"SOme important data2"
<br>
<br>
"SOme important data3"
</p>
```

Now i want to get the data seperatley as 
       "SOme important data1"
       SOme important data2
      SOme important data3

I am using simple html dom. But i dnt knw hw to fetch this data.

What i have tried:-

```
echo $html->find('p',0)->plaintext;
```

But this prints all the data, Hw to fetch the data seperately...Please help me out...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

An alternative depending on how you want the final data to be available in your code would be

```
foreach (explode('<br>', $html->find('p',0)->innertext) as $item) {
    $data[] = trim(strip_tags($item));
}

var_dump($data); // just for testing
```

Note the user if `innertext` rather than `plaintext`.  This leaves the 
 tags in the content to be used to split up the sentences into the array

This will split up the `<p>` tag content on 1 of the `<br>` tags into an array, loop over it, remove any trailing whitespace and any other `<br>` tags and present the final list of strings as the values of an array `$data`

Comment: I've just read the Simple HTML DOM documentation,  have you tried `$text = $html->find('text');` what does that output

Comment: `var_dump` it. does it contain your 3 sentences?

Comment: Yup var_dump($data) output is :- array(1) { [0]=> "SOme important data1""SOme important data2""SOme important data3"